Axios Error : Bad Request with status code 400 (in nodejs)
I have a simple code that is working on windows server 2019 node v14.21.3
But it doesn't work on my linux machine RHEL8 node v10.24.1 , v12.22.12, v16.20.2 , and v20.11.1 and my Windows 11 node v18.15.0 and v14.21.3
it is while I can run wget without any problem
wget https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

On windows server when the environment variable https_proxy
is empty it works. when the variable is set then it doesnt work.
But i need the variable for other jobs running on the machine.
On linux servers and windows 11 it doesnt matter if https_proxy is set or not. it doesnt work anyway. but when https_proxy is empty it will raise time out
here is the test.js
const axios = require ('axios');

(async () => {
  try
  {
    console.log('aaaa1');  
    const result = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    console.log('bbbbb1');  
    const response = result.data;
    console.log('ccccc1');  
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    console.log('ddddd1');  
  }
  catch (error)
  {
    console.log(error);
  }
})();

here is the package.json
{
  "name": "test_axios",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1"
  }
}

here is the output. i just replaced the username and proxy address

C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\axios>set
https_proxy=http://myproxy.mydomain:8080

C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\axios>set
https_proxy=http://myproxy.mydomain:8080

C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\axios>

C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\axios>node test.js

aaaa1

Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\axios\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\axios\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\axios\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:269:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {   config: {
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.4',
      host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    data: undefined   },   request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: false,
    socket: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'myproxy.mydomain',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      write: [Function: writeAfterFIN],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 6,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: null,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 58,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 183
    },
    _header: 'GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.21.4\r\n' +
      'host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 80,
      protocol: 'http:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype],
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
    path: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [Socket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 0,
      httpVersion: '1.0',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 400,
      statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
      client: [Socket],
      _consuming: true,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 2,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'myproxy.mydomain',
    protocol: 'http:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(errored)]: null,
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null   },   response: {
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headers: { connection: 'close' },
    config: {
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      method: 'get',
      headers: [Object],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      transitional: [Object],
      data: undefined
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.21.4\r\n' +
        'host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'myproxy.mydomain',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    data: 'Bad request'   },   isAxiosError: true,   toJSON: [Function: toJSON] }

C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\axios>



Why such an ancient version of Axios?

Check error.response.data for more clues

thanks for your attention. actually i simplified a third party code to make it easy to submit the issue. so i cannot upgrade axios.
you can see in the output error.response.data = "Bad request"

Does it work with a current version of axios? Does it work with fetch? It could be a bug in the 4 years old version of axios. If it's a bug in axios, you have 3 options: 1) update axios, 2) replace axios, 3) fix axios.

i tried with the latest version of axios.
no luck. the same error.
i tried fetch
var fetchUrl = require("fetch").fetchUrl;
fetchUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", function(error, meta, body){
console.log(error.toString());
console.log(body.toString());
});
it raises the following error
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.64.80.1:443

Maybe the proxy configuration is wrong or the proxy doesn't work as expected. Are the systems in different networks? Maybe it works, because the Windows Server system is in a network with Internet access and the other system aren't allowed to access the Internet. Can you add more debugging details? You wrote that you get a timeout when you use the proxy configuration. What happens when you don't use the proxy configuration. Who administrates the proxy server?

I think, this isn't a programming question, but a question for Super User or Server Fault. The code is correct. Have you tried to use the proxy server with a different tool?

Thanks, I believe proxy works, because  wget command works. Is there any specific proxy settings for node js?  Does it mean something is wrong with node?

No, I think there is something wrong with your system configuration or network configuration. I use Node.js for 10 years also in companies with proxies and I had no problems. Your description is unclear. It's lacking many necessary details.
